# Get second AttributeValue from SAML in php

Tags: php, saml, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

```
<saml:Attribute
xmlns:x500="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:profiles:attribute:X500"
x500:Encoding="LDAP"
NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri"
Name="urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.1.1.1"
FriendlyName="eduPersonAffiliation">
   <saml:AttributeValue
     xsi:type="xs:string">member</saml:AttributeValue>
   <saml:AttributeValue
     xsi:type="xs:string">staff</saml:AttributeValue>
 </saml:Attribute>
```

I want to get the second value (staff) out of SAML in my php code, the code looks exaclty like shown above. How can this be reached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SimpleSAMLphp's API](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-sp#section_6)

```
$as = new SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple('default-sp');
$as->requireAuth();
$attributes = $as->getAttributes();
// The attribute Name is the key
$secondValue = $attributes['urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.1.1.1'][1];
```